# What's the average reputation on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation

What is the average reputation on Stack Overflow, i.e. Total Reputation/Total Users?

Is there some retirement age for Stack Overflow users, so that their reputation stops increasing automatically beyond a certain time such as 75 years or greater?

Are there any other interesting Stack Overflow statistics, e.g. average age of users?

Comment: It has been a long time since then, any new answers for current data ?

Comment: Given the reputation points distribution, wouldn't the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) value (or similar) make more sense?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Head over to [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for that sort of thing.

Example [for reputation](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/261020), as of Nov 10 2017:

| average_rep | min_rep | max_rep | num_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 113 | 1 | 984476 | 7971132 |

(This is totally uninteresting due to the amount of 1-rep accounts.)

Also check out the [reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/).

For age: the age you enter in your profile info is:

1. Not mandatory
2. Not checked

So... I wouldn't trust that data. Currently for Stack Overflow the youngest members are 13yo (that's the minimum), the most senior members are 94yo, and the average is 29yo.

Comment: is it possible to exclude 1 rep people and calculate again?

Comment: A lot of fake ages here. I wonder if the 94yo account is real.

Comment: @simonzack: "huh, what's that, sonny? When I started we had to chisel our programs in stone!"

Comment: @simonzack I think that's the maximum age, so probably not.

Comment: Note that the age field has since been removed because GDPR

Answer (score 30):

Mat's query doesn't quite tell the whole story; that gives you the total average reputation across Stack Overflow, period.  There're a lot of accounts that weigh that average down, but there's something more interesting...

If we use the [bins](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) used in the Stack Overflow leagues, we arrive at [this result](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/261059/average-reputation-of-users-given-by-stack-overflows-total-reputation-boundaries) instead, which I find more interesting.

| Reputation Range | Average Reputation<sup>1</sup> |
| --- | --- |
| 1-199 | 8 |
| 200-499 | 340 |
| 500-999 | 701 |
| 1,000-1,999 | 1,401 |
| 2,000-2,999 | 2,440 |
| 3,000-3,999 | 3,839 |
| 5,000-9,999 | 6,929 |
| 10,000-24,999 | 15,127 |
| 25,000-49,999 | 34,396 |
| 50,000-99,999 | 67,892 |
| 100,000+ | 211,240 |

<sub>Update on  8/18/2023.</sub>

Answer (score 28):

| average_rep | min_rep | max_rep | num_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 316 | 2 | 736381 | 1509250 |

I tried excluding the 1 rep people and the data makes more sense now.

[Link to the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1776288/2157810) (as of Aug 17, 2023).

Comment: removing the under 12 rep people should be interesting too

Comment: I'm exactly at the average then

Comment: [Relvant query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1776288/2157810). As of posting average_rep is up to 416, and so is max_rep (1418176) and num_users (4597836).

Comment: It's interesting to see that even though the average reputation of all users has decreased from 126 in 2014 to 92 in 2023 (according to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281150/4284627), the answer currently says 113 but it was edited in 2017), the average reputation of users with >1 reputation has increased from 316 in 2014 to 416 in 2023. This means that the decrease in average reputation is only due to people creating accounts without participating, but the people who participate actually have a higher average reputation now than in 2014.

Answer (score 7):

I don't care so much how old a user is, but rather just what the relationship between years of account use and reputation.  I used SO heavily 5 years ago, but not so much lately, and I've been surprised that I've been able to keep my percentile ranking, but as you pointed out, good answers keep getting upvotes, so reputation does keep going up over time.

So I used [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1776331/average-reputation-by-user-years):

| CreatedYear | AverageReputation | NumUsers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2008 | 9571 | 21630 |
| 2009 | 3607 | 77937 |
| 2010 | 1284 | 199071 |
| 2011 | 765 | 358431 |
| 2012 | 360 | 678214 |
| 2013 | 168 | 1121274 |
| 2014 | 108 | 1173283 |
| 2015 | 81 | 1250649 |
| 2016 | 51 | 1513250 |
| 2017 | 32 | 1723737 |
| 2018 | 24 | 1641022 |
| 2019 | 16 | 1714267 |
| 2020 | 10 | 2196067 |
| 2021 | 5 | 2784205 |
| 2022 | 2 | 3053306 |
| 2023 | 1 | 1463743 |

I took off the NumUsers output to get [a more useful graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1776332/reputation-by-user-years#graph), which shows this is a logarithmic curve.

I'm guessing all the easy questions were asked and answered early, and the system doesn't reward duplication, so it's much harder for later users to post novel questions/answers that gain reputation.  There's just also plain old more time for questions to accumulate votes over time.  This theory didn't really pan out [in my individual case](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1776335/reputation-by-post-years#graph), but it did pan out in the all-user case, where we see [another logarithmic<sup>1</sup> curve](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1776328/reputation-by-post-years#graph).

The good news for new users:

- The Max score curves are severely distorted from statistical average curves.  You can get a good question/answer that puts you well above average for your join year.
- The oldest users with the highest average rankings are fewer in number.  The higher up you go, the fewer people you're competing against.
- Some of the other answers have pointed out the ridiculous number of 1 point users that you can easily surpass
- even 1 50 point bounty can put you on par with average 7 year old accounts.

<sup>1</sup>The averages rounding to nearest integer makes recent data look like a step function, but it's probably logarithmic if you had a true floating point average.

Comment: Please provide the query. "Above mentionned query system" means nothing as anwers order may not be the same later on.

Comment: It would be nice if you could like to the query, that way your answer will still be useful in the future when the numbers have changed.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I can go back and do that.  I started to and then realized I forgot to generate a new permalink for the second query and hosed the first one.

Answer (score 6):

I tried an average on [people having posted answers only](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1384924/average-reputation-for-answering-users)

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN nbAns >= 1 THEN Reputation END)
FROM (SELECT u.id as uid, COUNT(p.id) as nbAns
FROM Users as u
INNER JOIN Posts as p ON p.OwnerUserId = u.id
WHERE PostTypeId = 2
GROUP BY u.id) as countAns
INNER JOIN Users AS u on u.id = countAns.uid
```

Currently the average value is: 595