# What is the average impact score on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, statistics, people-reached

I have reached about 123k users. I was just wondering how this compares to other users on the site.

What is the average of the impact score of all users on Stack Overflow?

Comment: It is not easy to say, because the SEDE doesn't contain this information. You can get a good estimation by selecting, f.e. 100 random users by the SEDE, and checking their user page manually.

Comment: With the most likely distribution (most users have a very low value), the [median value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) is probably the more interesting number.

Comment: @peterh - You probably need to sample `SQRT(11817135)` or 3437 users. According to the [new users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate), the latest userid is 11817135. To get within one std deviation, you need to sample the square root of the population.

Comment: For a rep of 393, 123k is very very very above average. Though i notice some of your question on some very high view questions

Answer (score 22):

The answer is 63,112 give or take a few hundred (the [internal algorithm is slightly different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/158100), what I used here is the closest you will get with the public available data).

That is based on the score and views as they were last sunday 03:00 UTC.

The median is [957](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1078550) which might give a better indication for where you are (based on a suggestion from Editor in Chief Peter Mortensen)

You can calculate the average with this [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1078539):

```sql
Select Id
     , ParentId
     , OwnerUserId
     , Score
     , PostTypeId
     , cast(isnull(viewcount,0) as bigint) ViewCount
Into #Posts
From Posts
Where owneruserid is not null

-- create index ix_id on #Posts(id)
-- create index ix_PosttypeId on #Posts(Posttypeid)

Select Id
     , ParentId
     , OwnerUserId
     , Score
     , PostTypeId
     , ViewCount
Into #PostsQ
From #Posts
Where PostTypeid = 1

Select Id
     , ParentId
     , OwnerUserId
     , Score
     , PostTypeId
     , ViewCount
Into #PostsA
From #Posts
Where PostTypeid = 2
and score > 0

-- create index ix_score on #PostsA(score desc)

create index ix_idq on #PostsQ(id)
-- create index ix_Parentidq on #PostsQ(parentid, OwnerUserid)
-- create index ix_ida on #Postsa(id)
create index ix_Parentida on #Postsa(parentid, OwnerUserid, score desc)


select avg(sum_of_viewcount)
from (
select sum(viewcount) Sum_of_viewcount, p.owneruserid as reached
from #posts p
inner join (
  Select Id, OwnerUserId 
  From #PostsQ 
  Union
  Select ParentId, OwnerUserId
    From #Posts p
    inner join votes v on v.postid = p.iD
   Where VoteTypeId = 1  --  Id in (select AcceptedAnswerId from Posts)
  Union
  Select ParentId, OwnerUserId
    From #PostsA
   Where Score > 5
  Union
  Select a.ParentId, a.OwnerUserId
    From #PostsA a
         Join #PostsQ q On a.ParentId = q.Id
   Where a.Score > 0.20 * (select sum(Score) from #PostsA where ParentId=q.Id)
    --  And a.Score > 0
  Union
  Select x.ParentId, x.OwnerUserId 
    From (Select a.ParentId , a.OwnerUserId, Rank() Over(Partition By a.ParentId, a.OwnerUserId Order By ta.Score Desc) AnswerRank
            From #PostsA a
                 Join #PostsA ta On ta.ParentId = a.ParentId
           -- Where a.Score > 0
          ) x
          Where AnswerRank <= 3) 
rp on rp.id = p.iD
group by p.owneruserid
) data
```

I needed to so some juggling due to timeouts I got when I forked of one of my similar queries found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253596/158100). That is why there are temp tables there with specific indexes.

Comment: Around a month ago when I checked my profile they were 59k but now idk how they got reduced to 23k :{

Comment: @Lighteninger probably a competing answer that pushed an answer of yours out of the top 3.

Comment: Means the top three answers on a question increase the OP's people reached threshold?

Comment: @Lighteninger yes, it is the last select query in the union that accounts for those huge jumps if you have an answer on a popular (read many views) question.

Comment: With the most likely distribution, the median value is probably the more interesting number (but it may be difficult to compute).

Comment: I got 1.6 million, i think it's considered a lot

Comment: Ah you got 3.4 million

Comment: Ugh ouch Jon Skeet got 277.4 million

Comment: Is, for example, user [sudha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11700383/sudha?tab=profile) counted (*"0 people reached"*)? Should or shouldn't such users be counted? Related: [What about 1-rep accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281147/whats-the-average-reputation-on-stack-overflow/281152#281152) (that can have [more than 0 people reached](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9192980/pranav-panday?tab=profile))?

Comment: @PeterMortensen but that user is excluded already as they have no posts, those should be (and are) excluded. And I don't think there are questions with a viewcount of zero and answers are only taken into account when they have a positive score.

Comment: @U10-Forward It's because you've been spam-answering old questions with (arguably poor) answers... now that aside, your "impact" is basically summed with the total #views on those old questions, once your answers reach +5 rep.

Comment: The takeaway is to take your "impact" with a grain of salt. It seldom reports an accurate value (especially if you're in the habit of answering old questions), and unless you're a relatively old user with a lot of established answers (or Jon Skeet), it does not mean much.

Comment: @cs95 but ... I'm here for the impact ....

Comment: I hate that score so much. Fuzzy number for the sake of a number.

Comment: 18.6 million boom

Comment: @U10-Forward Which proves how crappy an indicator it is. 5% of the world's population are programmers and read Jon Skeet posts? Yeah right.

Comment: @Lundin <sub>programmers</sub> python programmers don't, i at maximum only saw ten of his posts

Comment: Maybe the real question to ask here is how impact correlates with rep.

Comment: @U12-Forward you have around [10 million views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZE3B.png) mostly from the answers that have less than 10 upvotes.